# Kafka consumer returning from poll earlier than the set pollTimeout?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created a Kafka consumer (Using KafkaListener interface) using the Spring Kafka starter. I set the pollTimeout in the containerFactory for my consumer. I set it to 5 seconds. When I send a batch of 100 messages at once I notice my consumer will grab some messages from the batch but not all of them. I was anticipating that the consumer would wait for 5 seconds waiting for additional records?

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(pollTimeout);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
    return factory;
}
```

config values that I'm setting:

```
kafka_consumer_concurrency: "1"
kafka_consumer_max_poll_interval_ms: "290000"
kafka_consumer_enable_auto_commit: "false"
kafka_consumer_request_timeout_ms: "300000"
kafka_consumer_fetch_max_wait_ms: "1000"
kafka_consumer_fetch_min_bytes: "50000000"
kafka_consumer_fetch_max_bytes: "52428800"
kafka_consumer_partition_fetch_max_bytes: "52428800"
kafka_consumer_poll_timeout_ms: "280000"
```

Kafka fetch request log statement:

```
[DEBUG] 20:50:08.028 [-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=consumer_listener] Using older server API v6 to send FETCH 

{replica_id=-1,max_wait_time=1000,min_bytes=50000000,max_bytes=52428800,isolation_level=0,topics=[{topic=test-topic,partitions=[{partition=1,fetch_offset=988786,log_start_offset=-1,partition_max_bytes=52428800},

{partition=0,fetch_offset=1619712,log_start_offset=-1,partition_max_bytes=52428800},

{partition=2,fetch_offset=989663,log_start_offset=-1,partition_max_bytes=52428800}]}]} with correlation id 832 to node 124
```

Exact same issue is reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026796/kafka-consumer-returning-from-poll-earlier-than-the-set-polltimeout)

Answer (score 1):

The poll timeout is simply how long we will wait until at least one record is available.

There is no `poll.min.records` only `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms`.

> `fetch.min.bytes`
>
> The minimum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. If insufficient data is available the request will wait for that much data to accumulate before answering the request. The default setting of 1 byte means that fetch requests are answered as soon as a single byte of data is available or the fetch request times out waiting for data to arrive. Setting this to something greater than 1 will cause the server to wait for larger amounts of data to accumulate which can improve server throughput a bit at the cost of some additional latency.
>
> `fetch.max.wait.ms`
>
> The maximum amount of time the server will block before answering the fetch request if there isn't sufficient data to immediately satisfy the requirement given by fetch.min.bytes.

Comment: Hi Gary thanks for imparting your expertise on this! So I'm not looking for 
 a setting like `poll.min.records` but something that will make my consumer wait X amount of seconds for records - and then return with whatever it has. Is that what is achieved with `fetch.max.wait.ms`?

Comment: So if my consumer makes a fetch request it can return with nothing even if there is data because that may be set through `fetch.min.bytes`. The server will not serve the consumer fetch request until it's at least got `fetch.min.bytes` or until `fetch.max.wait.ms` has expired. But what if my `fetch.max.wait.ms` is set to 500 ms and pollTimeout is set to 200ms? The pollTimeout will always be < `fetch.max.wait.ms` so the server will only ever fulfill the fetch request once we have more than `fetch.min.bytes` correct?

Comment: In my most recent test I set `max.poll.records` = 1000, `fetch.min.bytes` = 100000000,  `fetch.max.wait.ms` = 1000, and `pollTimeout` = 5000.  I send repeated batches of 1000 records (each sized 1kb (total 1mb which is less than `fetch.min.bytes`) and sometimes my consumer recieves all 1000 at once, and other times it breaks it up and process int multiple batches when I would like it to wait the configured time `fetch.max.wait.ms`. Is there something I haven't set correctly?

Comment: If the poll timeout is shorter, the fetch still happens in the background and (e.g with poll timeout 5 seconds and fetch wait 6 seconds) the records will be retrieved on the next poll. In your case (500ms, 200ms), it would take 3 polls to get the records (if there are not enough bytes). Generally, the poll timeout should be higher than the fetch max wait. As I said, there is no mechanism to wait until 1000 records are ready, only the max wait time and max bytes. The fact that they are broken up sometimes is probably due to timing.

Comment: Gary did you mean to say (500ms, 200ms) for `fetch.max.wait.ms` and poll timeout respectively? that would make sense then for it to take 3 polls if I'm understanding it in this way  - if I make a fetch request the server will start a timer.  Then I continue to fetch until time elapsed since initial fetch is greater than `fetch.max.wait.ms` then the server will return the data to the fetcher and the fetch timer will be reset? Even if this is true I'm not quite sure I understand why the timing results in them being broken up.

Comment: As I said, I recommend using a higher poll timeout over fetch max wait. The fetch will wait for the fetch wait or min bytes to show up; whichever comes first. If you are seeing something different, I can't explain it. I don't know of any condition that would cause those properties to not be used. You can see the fetch activity by enabling DEBUG logging for `org.apache.kafka`.

Comment: I set the max poll timeout to a pretty high number ~ 4 minutes and the `max.fetch.wait.ms` at 1 second. I also set the other fetch parameter values for bytes very high so that I could force kafka to only send the data either when it has gotten the `max.poll.records` or reached `max.fetch.wait.ms`. Posted my config paramaters but I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: I've also taken a look at the logs for Kafka. I put the fetch request log statement in the post but nothing really stands out to me. It looks like it makes a fetch request - returns almost immediately with < max.poll.records and then makes subsequent fetch requests

Comment: I don't recognize these properties `kafka_consumer_fetch_max_wait_ms` - perhaps post a smal verifiable sample someplace, that exhibits the behavior you see and I'll take a look.